# Is the number of duplicate accounts on the uprise?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts, duplicate-accounts

Something I'm seeing on an almost daily (at the very least weekly) basis now is a question which is either an exact duplicate, or very closely follow on question from one I have seen previously but posted by a **different** account. Take, for example, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59581794/3484879), where it is clearly a follow on question from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59566397/3484879).

Something I had done previously is raised custom flags about these, but (for lack of better words) I'm getting tired of doing these, and also I'm not sure how well received they would be. I *suspect* the reason that these people are raising these questions on different account is because of a question ban, so they use a new/different account.

I know there is nothing wrong with having multiple accounts, but an important thing about them is that the accounts do not interact. Surely something like this counts as a kind of *interaction*; "I didn't receive the answer I wanted wanted, or it was poorly received. I can't ask a new question, so I'll use a different account to continue or recreate the thread". Is this opinion correct?

Custom moderator flags for things like this can literally take days to be resolved (this isn't a rant about that at all), and these (almost always) low quality questions are then answered and then OP "gets" what they want. Is there something better we can be doing to combat what is effectively an abuse of the system?

Other examples I've seen recently and flagged:

- [What to do when someone keeps creating new accounts to ask the same bad question?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59490020/3484879) duplicate of [SQL Server : Please help, sum of related records parent and child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59488929/3484879)
- [Combobox Binding SQL Server Vb.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59359267/3484879) duplicate of [How I Do Select Query SQL Server Vb.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59357309/3484879), which is a duplicate of [Search data by Combobox vb.net sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59352174/3484879), which is a duplicate of [How Show Column Result in Combobox vb.net SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59351049/3484879) (there was also a further duplicate of this post after I flagged).
- [Must declare the scalar variable “@AccessLevel”. in SQL Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59102802/3484879) follow on of [String or binary data would be truncated when using it in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59102047/3484879).

Like I mention in the comments of the first question I link to, I feel that often us answering these qusetions is actually a disservice to the user. If they don't understand the previous answer they got, then why are they not asking about it? Why are we (the Community) not trying to educate them so they can expand on the answer. *Though, I admit, some of the users are probably asking the question (demanding the answer) out of a sense of "entitlement", and they will never try to or want to learn.*

These are just examples I see, and I stick exclusively to the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) related tags (I dread to think what this is like for those of you who have a larger skill set).

Many of us are aware that the quality of posts on SO is sinking very quickly, and posts and actions such as these are really not helping the situation. I don't want to be "policing" the problem, but I also don't want to reading the same question 2/3 times a week, and of the same low quality it was last time. it does not make for an "enjoyable" experience on the site.

Edit: When I can, I do "Gold Badge" these, however, because many are low quality they don't get an answer or not one that is marked as the solution or upvoted. Also, as they aren't the same account, I can't mark them as an exact duplicate. This means the only option is a custom flag, if i want to take some kind of action; as the previous question(s) won't be valid duplicate candidates.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind it is may not necessarily be duplicate accounts - but students in the same class who have the same homework.

Comment: I agree on this, @psubsee2003, but most of the ones I've linked to actually even use the same descriptions in their questions. I can understand us seeing the same data, and examples, but the wording around it would at least be different, as would the attempts (if they have tried and evidenced it).

Comment: Or copy and paste from the same assignment.  Not disputing your concerns just raising an alternative argument for *some* of these

Comment: I agree the wording is exactly the same but on the other hand both users have more than 200 rep. It's not *that* much but it seems unlikely that a single person who posts the same content from both will get that much rep.

Comment: I confronted an asker of a self-duplicate a few days ago and was surprised to learn that apparently the new closure UI encourages re-posting: [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547435/how-to-insert-first-maps-data-to-another-map#comment105263930_59547435). Perhaps they're just trying to follow the instructions they've been given with their puppets?

Comment: @scohe001 "you can edit the question or ask a new one" is not new as far as I know... I believe that confusing guidance was there always... But it never suggests to use new accounts...

Comment: [Typical example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392073/why-is-my-question-considered-off-topic-when-it-objectively-isnt).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few different heuristics we can use to detect duplicate accounts. I picked one that minimizes false positives:

[image: rises slowly from September to peak about November 18th and then gradually decline through the end of the year]

...and another that minimizes false negatives:

[image: much larger numbers, but again the high point is about November 18th]

(if you're wondering: these are *sloooooow* to gather, even for just a quarter...)

So, short answer is: the high point for this quarter of 2019 was in November (none too surprising); current volume is down a bit, but will probably rise as we get a little further into the year.